# Wrap Text in xsl:value-of

Tags: html, xslt

In my xslt I have:

```
<TD>
 <xsl:variable name="RESTEXT">
    <xsl:value-of select="$RESULT"/>
 </xsl:variable>
</TD>
```

The value of $RESULT can sometime contain many characters. I want to wrap it if it is larger then 40 characters and show the rest in the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `<xsl:value-of select="substring($RESULT, 1, 40)"/>` should answer your needs.

The `string-length()` function might also be helpful to you to create the second line (it will display the text from the 41st character to the last one):

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($RESULT) &gt; 40">
  <TD><xsl:value-of select="substring($RESULT, 41)" /></TD>
</xsl:if>
```